# WCF SOAP proxy fails calling API Management, works with Postman

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-api-management

We have a SOAP proxy generated using Visual Studio connected services tooling (VS2017).

- When we call an .asmx endpoint the SOAP proxy works perfectly.
- When we communication to API Management endpoint, which is directed to go to
  the same .asmx endpoint it fails.
- When we communicate using Postman to API Managemenet endpoint the
  call works, we took the HTTP headers and the SOAP body from a fiddler trace.

**So in summary**

We know the .asmx endpoint works when using the SOAP client and also postman.

We know API Management works over Postman, but not using the SOAP client generated by the tooling from the WCF.

We basically get back a 404 when calling API management and a small JSON body returned

```
{ "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }
```

I just can't understand why the same response passed out over Postman works, but fails in the underlying WCF SOAP generated client.

Any one got an idea's why this may be failing?

One interesting thing to note is I tried the call using a HTTPClient, I passed in the headers and SOAP envelope and the call worked from C#. So it must be something to do with the underlying WCF infrastructure and API Management, but I just can't determine what that could be, particularly as the SOAP client works when talking to the ASMX service directly.

Comment: Do you see any difference in Fiddler traces when called from Postman and from generated proxy? Perhaps you could share them.

Comment: Absolutely none Vitaliy, they are an exact match.

Comment: What about difference in call to SOAP directly from proxy, and through APIM? Are there any difference besides URI?

Comment: Same thing Vitaliy, no differences. I'm a pretty experienced developer and this one has me stumped. I've spent about a day and a half going thru every option I could think of. Even down to removing XML ordering off the XML schema that was generated in case it was a deserialisation issue. At this stage, I'm going to take the XML object definitions that were code generated (there are 100's of them) and hand write a proxy using a HTTPClient and generate the SOAP envelope myself injecting the XML for each request into the SOAP envelope.

Comment: At least that way I'll have full control and visibility of what is happening and I know a HTTPClient call works with both the ASMX endpoint and the APIM endpoint.

Comment: Hm... Do you have any sort of repro I could try?

Comment: Thanks for the offer Vitaliy but unfortunately not at the moment, the services are not publicly available but I'll need to go thru security department to open this up. I'll see if I get time over the next couple of days to repo this in a publicly available ASMX service and stick APIM on top of it. But I'm working on the work around at the moment so time is limited.

Answer (score 1):

Just could not get to the bottom of this. I ended up rewriting the proxy manually using a HTTP client. I took the code generated XML entities from the tooling, removed all XML attributes and treated them just like POCO. I wrote a wrapper to generate the SOAP Envelope and read the corresponding result and serialize them back into the POCO objects.
Worked like a charm.